# How to implement margin changes from Chrome DevTool

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, google-chrome-devtools

I made [this website](https://barautoankauf.ch/) for my dad's business and you can see a contact form if you scroll a bit down. I'd like us to go to the Mobile View of the page through Google's DevTool (<kbd>F12</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>; or left besides "Elements"). I will show you what's wrong.
If you go to where it says "Treibstoff", try selecting the 4 different options. You will notice that you can't select the bottom two, "Diesel" and "Elektro".
Well, you can actually. If you press slightly above of the end of the word, but you can't select it like one usually does.

If we inspect the elements (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), we see that the box of "Typenscheinnr." is overlapping "Diesel" and "Elektro" (Inspect a bit above "Typenscheinnr.", not directly on it). A fix I found for this is: Inspect click the big overlapping box of "Typenscheinnr.", scroll down under Styles until you see that multilayered box, set upper margin to 45 with doubleclick.

This should fix it, but I don't know how to make this change go live. I did some research and all I got were solutions similar to "do !important" and then some code. Those were also for the whole site or something like that ...

Anyway, any help would be appreciated and I'm again sorry if this question is stupid. If there's more information you'd like to know, by all means just ask me.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Just use `clear: both`

If you place a `<div style="clear: both"></div>` right before the end of the *Treibstoff:* `<p>` tag, the behavior will be the expected one.

This happens because you are using `float`

Comment: Like this? `<p><span>Treibstoff:</span><span class="radio">[radio treibstoff use_label_element "Benzin" "Gas"]
[radio treibstoff use_label_element "Diesel" "Elektro"]</span><div style="clear: both"></div></p></div>`

Comment: It worked! Thanks from both of us!! Have a nice week :)